# Would an effervescent tablet react with itself if ground into a nanopowder?

Tags: acid-base, surface-chemistry, mechanochemistry

[Effervescent tablets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effervescent_tablet) usually are a mixture of a weak acid, base, and binder. When dry there is no reaction. But when placed in water the acid-base neutralization releases CO2 rapidly.

If you ground a (dry) tablet into nanopowder, the acid and base grains would have enormous surface area. Would this cause them to react despite having no solvent?

Comment: Anyway, you will just obtain a surface reaction, producing the tiniest amount of gas, despite the huge surface area. Furthermore, the residual solid stuff will prevent new fresh molecules from coming into contact one another. So the rection will quickly stop.

Comment: There is possibility of water vapor adsorption and autocatalysis by produced water. Anyway, avoid sneezing toward nanopowders.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34916/how-might-ammonia-be-created-in-this-mechanochemical-reaction

Comment: I guess it would react, but you'd need long time and/or temperature, not to mention water vapor in the air would influence it.